# Install HDBC with Stack

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm one hour into using Stack but have hit a roadblock.

I want to use

```
import Database.HDBC
import Database.HDBC.Sqlite3
```

in my code. HDBC seems to be on [stackage](https://www.stackage.org/package/HDBC) but I can't work out how to configure for its use

I have already executed `https://www.stackage.org/package/HDBC`, and have this in my `.cabal` file

```
library
  hs-source-dirs:      src
  exposed-modules:     Lib
                     , CrawlerHTTP
                     , DbHandler
  build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5
                     , wreq
                     , lens
                     , containers
                     , aeson
                     , lens-aeson
                     , HDBC
  default-language:    Haskell2010
```

And I've tried adding this to my `.yaml` file

```
# Extra package databases containing global packages
extra-package-dbs:
- HDBC-2.4.0.1
```

Where you see capitals I've also tried lowercase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use

```
extra-deps:
- HDBC-2.4.0.1
```

Comment: Can you explain more? Why will Simon want to use that?

Comment: Thanks. I'd just worked out that I had used the wrong part of the yaml file but this sped me along.